# Sliding (the same) image on/off the screen but without using any extra UIImageViews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but wanted to find out before I do it another way. So I have my main view, and in the centre is an `UIImageView` which I've declared and synthesized. I want to slide the image off the screen and slide another on. But I to do this with the same `UIImageView`. I want slide it off, and slide the same view back on but with a different image.

Not sure how it can be done in this way. I was thinking maybe create a temporary image view that's equal to the current, add it to the view in the same frame, and then slide the temporary one off the view and the main image view back on.

Would like your opinions on this.

Comment: What's the problem using one image view, do you need to have both the new an old images animated on the screen simultaneously ?

Comment: Yes, where one pushes the other out. I don't think it's possible without at least creating a temporary imageview.

Comment: Well, I believe you can render an image content without an `UIImageView` with CoreGraphics right on UIView's layer :) As two image-views replacement it would be an overkill for the simple cases, so that's not an answer, just a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did some playing around and found a rather simple solution.

```
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:myNewImageString];

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:1];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[self.myImageView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SlideOutandInImagek"];
```

It appears that the previous image is retained before the new image is set. Works like a dream.

Thanks for all the comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment, it is not possible to have two images on screen using on UIImageView, so yes you will have to create a temp one, but it doesn't have to stay around for very long, just set your synthesized one to the temp one in the completion argument of `UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion` and let the temp one go out of scope (if it is ARC) or release it (non-ARC).